# XSLT - Apply two different template in sequence

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document like this:

```
<parent>
    <child>hello world</child>
</parent>
```

I want to apply two different transformations:

- From "hello world" to "hello guys" (using the replace function)
- From "hello guys" to "HELLO GUYS" (using the translation funciont)

For this reason, my XSLT stylesheet i something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- First Transformation -->
<xsl:template match="text()" >
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(. , 'world', 'guys')"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Second Transformation -->
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
</xsl:template>
```

The output is:

```
<parent>
    <child>HELLO WORLD</child>
</parent>
```

You can notice that I get HELLO WORLD and not HELLO GUYS... I think that I can solve this problem making the replace function inside the translate function. Unfortunatelly I need to have this two operation well separated (for this reason I used two different template element). How can I achive this?

Comment: You would need to store the first result in a variable and then apply another template in a different mode on the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you explain me how I can store the first result in a variable?

Comment: If you want **all** text nodes to be processed in the same manner (i.e by both replace and translate), then you should have **one** template that does both. Having two templates makes sense only if you want some nodes to be processed differently than others (note that none of the answers given so far will allow you to do that).

Comment: BTW, since you're obviously using an XSLT 2.0 processor (otherwise `replace()` would not work), you should also use the `upper-case()` function instead of the awkward `translate()` that was necessary in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a mode with

```
<!-- First Transformation -->
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="t1" as="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(. , 'world', 'guys')"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$t1" mode="mode1"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Second Transformation -->
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="mode1">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
</xsl:template>
```

then you can use two templates where one processes the result of another.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I'm not sure on why it works: during the first transformation I make the replace and then I store the (partial) result in a variable named t1. Then I apply the second transformation in this variable. Is this right? Why there's no t1 call in the second transformation?

Comment: The variable holds the text node created by the `<xsl:value-of select="replace(. , 'world', 'guys')"/>`. The `apply-templates` then selects that text node for processing in a different mode and the `match` and `mode` suffice to do the processing. With your original template you do not need a variable either to reference a node.

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one template match the text() nodes.
But you can use named templates 
Try:

```
<!-- First Transformation -->
<xsl:template name="replace" >
    <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($text , 'world', 'guys')"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Second Transformation -->
<xsl:template name="translate">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="." />
        <xsl:value-of select="translate($text, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" >
    <xsl:variable name="step1">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:call-template name="translate">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$step1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works! If I well understand, this XSLT store the result of the first transformation in a variable called step1 and then it make the second transformation using this variable. Is this right? Thanks again